# unable to clip raster(ETrF.etrf.tif) in python?

Tags: python-2.7, arcgis, arcpy

I have 50 rasters saved as LC81520412017282LGN00_ETrF.etrf.tif , and a polygon shapefile saved as a .shp.

as tried to clip this image using Clip(Data Management) in arcgis , it woks fine.but to process all image in bulk , I have written a script as below

```
import os
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "E:/Project"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('E:/Project/a/r'):
    for file in files:
        if os.path.splitext(file)[1] == '.tif':
           print (file)
           arcpy.Clip_management(file,"#",
           "E:/Project/be/test.gdb/%file%"
           ,"be/canal.shp","#","Clipping 
           Geometry", "NO_MAINTAIN_EXTENT")
```

the above script throws an error of "unsupported file or file doesn't exist".

Answer (score 0):

the clip management is only to clip a shapefile to "Cut" a raster file using a shapefile you have to use

```
ExtractByMask (in_raster, in_mask_data)
```

here is an example

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
env.workspace = "C:/sapyexamples/data"
outExtractByMask = ExtractByMask("elevation", "mask.shp")
outExtractByMask.save("C:/sapyexamples/output/maskextract")
```

Comment: there is an other Clip tool in Data management which uses for raster images.